# aws cors issue with createPresignedPost using nextJS

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js

I am attempting to upload an image from NextJs to AWS S3 to a public bucket using AWS SDK v3  createPresignedPost.

I am getting a cors error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://saintly-sinners-public-bucket.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 204.
```

I have the Bucket  policy

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id":"publicBacket1",
"Statement": [
        {
                "Sid": "hidden",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Principal": "*",
                "Action": ["s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
                ],
                "Resource": 
                        "arn:aws:s3:::saint-sinners-public-backet"
        }
]
```

}

I copied the bucket id from the AWS
Bucket ARN
arn:aws:s3:::saintly-sinners-public-bucket

When I attempt to save this I get the error
Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

I have the CORS policy

```
[
 {
    "AllowedHeaders": [
        "*"
    ],
    "AllowedMethods": [
        "GET",
        "PUT"
    ],
    "AllowedOrigins": [
        "*"
    ],
    "ExposeHeaders": [
        "ETag"
    ],
    "MaxAgeSeconds": 3600
 }
 ]
```